# Python - storing integer array to disk for efficient retrieval

Tags: python

I have a large integer array that I need to store in a file, what is the most efficient way so I can have quick retrieval speed? I'm not concerned with efficiency of writing to disk, but reading only
I am wondering if there is a good solution other than json and pickle?

Comment: maybe using numpy could help? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: So did you try JSON and found it too slow for your needs?

Comment: json is probably the fastest way that you can achieve with python ... (short of keeping it in memory)  ...

Comment: Maybe [mmap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) will suit your needs.

Comment: @TimPietzcker it's currently the bottleneck with json so I am looking for possible alternatives

Answer (score 1):

JSON/pickle are very low efficiency solutions as they require at best several memory copies to get your data in or out.

Keep you data binary if you want the best efficiency. The pure python approach would involve using struct.unpack, however this is a little kludgy as you still need a memory copy.

Even better is something like numpy.memmap which directly maps your file to a numpy array. Very fast, very memory efficient. Problem solved. You can also write your file using the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

[msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) will probably beat json in terms of performance in loading data. Or, at least, msgpack beats json in [my tests](https://twitter.com/wojtekwalczak/status/437252753673711616) in loading many large files. Yet another possibility is to try [HDF5 for Python](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/):

> HDF5 is an open-source library and file format for storing large
>   amounts of numerical data, originally developed at NCSA. It is widely
>   used in the scientific community for everything from NASA’s Earth
>   Observing System to the storage of data from laboratory experiments
>   and simulations. Over the past few years, HDF5 has rapidly emerged as
>   the de-facto standard technology in Python to store large numerical
>   datasets.

In your case I would go for HDF5.